# How to create a draggable object using SlimDX?

Tags: c#, slimdx

Using SlimDX is it possible to make an object that I can drag?  Given that the language is being used in 3D games I'd have to assume yes, but I don't see any examples on it.  What would be involved?

I know I'd need to program a way for SlimDX to know I'm selecting an onscreen object rather than repositioning the camera, but I don't know how to go about this.

Comment: Well, first you need to know where your objects are in 2D relevance to the camera's orientation at the time the mouse click happens.  That's some tricky math I can't really help you on.  But once you know where the objects are in 2D to the current view point, simple use hit detection, via something simple like using the Rectangle class to determine if a Point resides in Said Rectangle or rolling your own polygon/point hit detection system (more math).  Once you know the object was clicked, simple convert the mouses position back to the objects new 3D coordinates.